# Get Middleware Data and Use in a Class or Controller - ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-middleware

I have some middleware that currently logs request info from the context that was taken from the docs for debugging purposes:

```
public class RequestLoggerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestLoggerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("init");
        
        var pathbase = configuration["PATH_BASE"];
        
        // Request method, scheme, and path
        _logger.LogDebug("Request Method: {METHOD}", context.Request.Method);
        _logger.LogDebug("Request Scheme: {SCHEME}", context.Request.Scheme);
        _logger.LogDebug("Request Path: {PATH}", context.Request.Path);
        _logger.LogDebug("Context Base Path: {PATHBASE}", context.Request.PathBase);
        _logger.LogDebug("Env Base Path: {PATH_BASE}", pathbase); 
        _logger.LogDebug("Host: {HOST}", context.Request.Host.Value);
        
        // Connection: RemoteIp
        _logger.LogDebug("Request RemoteIp: {REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS}", context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress);

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

I would like to use some of this like the `RemoteIpAddress` and add some more contextual information like the machine id to this, and pass the data to another class, or a controller, to do something with.

I'm not sure if the `HttpContext` that is getting passed in to the `InvokeAsync` method can be passed or injected into a regular class or controller and yield the same information, hence why I am asking this question.

Comment: Check the docs for information on how to access the HttpContext https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: That's very helpful thanks, probably go with the dependency injection example for what I need.  One thing I noticed is that the Controller example was inheriting from `Controller`.  I normally work more with Apis, so I inherit from `ControllerBase`.  Is the `Context` part of this base class?

Comment: yes it is on controllerbase